# Upgrade CakePHP from 2.1 to 2.8+

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm sure I should upgrade my project from 2.1 to 2.8+
But how hard would it be? Anyone have some experience like this?
Are there any "dos and don'ts" I should know (apart those from the man)?

Comment: To those looking for simply how to do this: overwrite your `lib/Cake` with the one from the [latest `2.x` distribution](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how hard would it be? Anyone have some experience like this?

How hard it is depends on the quality of your code and how close you stayed to the principles of the framework. If you used it well and followed its conventions and didn't change core classes or made any other big stupid thing it should be just a matter of following the migration guides.

> Are there any "dos and don'ts" I should know (apart those from the man)?

No, just follow the migration guides. Every version has one that describes the changes. Here is the one for 2.8, I'm sure you'll be able to find the others.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-8-migration-guide.html

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade directly from 2.0 to 2.8? Or should we upgrade to each consecutive versions 2.1, 2.2 etc?

Comment: Of course you can. But you'll have a lot more changes to test then. That is the reason why you try to stay up to date.